# Common.Logging package update not compatible with Log4Net

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I have a dependency for Common.Logging.Log4Net1213 in my project and when trying to update it, i get:

> Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Log4Net 2.0.8' is not compatible with
>   'Common.Logging.Log4Net1213 3.4.1 constraint: Log4Net (= 2.0.3)'.

Why is this happening? I have Log4Net 2.8, so an earlier version of Common.Logging.Log4Net1213 is compatible with Log4Net 2.8 and the last version is not? I just don't understand.

Thank you for help.

Comment: You could just remove Log4Net and its dependencies from your project and install it in your needed version again. It should load all needed dependencies by its own via NuGet.

Comment: I have spent FAR longer than I care to, dealing with this issue. I see one of the replies has been marked as the answer, but what did you actually do to fix/workaround? Hopefully you remember, but I would not blame you if you moved on from this one swiftly! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On official, www.nuget.org website said that Common.Logging.Log4Net1213 logging framework has dependencies on Common.Logging (>= 3.4.1) and Log4Net (= 2.0.3). Unfortunately, as you can see there is no support for Log4Net version (2.0.8).

Please verify this description: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Common.Logging.Log4Net1213/

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. I tried the Common.Logging.Log4Net208 and it worked for me.
You should first uninstall the Common.Logging.Log4Net1213 package and then install the new one. All the dependencies as Log4Net 2.0.8.0 will be installed.

And don't forget to modify all your App.config of all your different environments as below:

```
<logging>
  <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4net208">
    <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
  </factoryAdapter>
</logging>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [tags of "Common.Logging.Log4Net" on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22Common.Logging.Log4Net%22), unless I'm mistaken, it looks like there is a version that is compatible with 2.0.8: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Common.Logging.Log4Net208/